# CSS for floating divs with ellipsis -- widths are unknown

Tags: html, css

How can two divs float side by side where left will show ellipsis and the right side will not wrap?

This is the desired result:

[image: Final Result]

The thing is, I need to do this without specifying a width for the left and right divs.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8hhhjc0/1/

When the width is specified, it works. Without the widths, the right div is pushed down:

[image: problem]

Is it possible to not specify a width for the left and right divs?  The right div is always small.

`Note:` In the jsFiddle, I only have control over the div tags, the surrounding table can have a variable width based on user preferences.

Comment: You have use table already, why don't you make whole thing as table row and cell, rather than the divs?

Comment: I cannot use a table as this is getting plugged into an already built framework which interacts with the mouseover event and the framework is only reacting off of divs.  Tables is not an option.  I have not tired using things like `display:table-row;`.

Comment: I think the `ellipsis` requires a width to figure out where to start ellipsing... it is a bit of a hack, but you can use something like `width: 80%` in your left divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the float in your css
and place your div top right first

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="topRight">12:30pm</div>
<div class="topLeft">Firstl line, this is long line and needs to show eclipise</div>
```

Then your css woule be

```
.topLeft {
xxxwidth:215px;
text-overflow:ellipsis;    
overflow:hidden;
word-wrap:break-word;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfmny0a4/

Comment: This is working nicely in Chrome, FF and IE!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1:** Do it with CSS `table`, requires to have fixed width of second column.

http://jsfiddle.net/pbw2jdc8/ (adjust the output frame narrower and see)

```css
.outer {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.topLeft, .botLeft {
    display: table-cell;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.topRight, .botRight {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:270px;border:1px solid grey;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="topLeft">Firstl line, this is long line and needs to show eclipise</div>
                    <div class="topRight">12:30pm</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="botLeft">Second line also long and needs to show eclipise</div>
                    <div class="botRight"><img height='16' width='16' src='http://s12.postimg.org/jbo7bw449/test.png'/></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Approach 2:** Using CSS [`flexbox`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), no fixed width is required.

http://jsfiddle.net/ktmwqqzk/ (adjust the output frame narrower and see)

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
}
.topLeft, .botLeft {
    flex: 1 1 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.topRight, .botRight {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:270px;border:1px solid grey;table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="topLeft">Firstl line, this is long line and needs to show eclipise</div>
                <div class="topRight">12:30pm</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="botLeft">Second line also long and needs to show eclipise</div>
                <div class="botRight"><img height='16' width='16' src='http://s12.postimg.org/jbo7bw449/test.png'/></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Approach 3:** The float first trick, again `table-layout:fixed` is required to ensure both text boxes to `ellipsis` correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/rmLsa5aw/ (adjust the output frame narrower and see)

```css
.topLeft, .botLeft {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.topRight, .botRight {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:270px;border:1px solid grey;table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="topRight">12:30pm</div>
            <div class="topLeft">Firstl line, this is long line and needs to show eclipise</div>
            <div class="botRight"><img height='16' width='16' src='http://s12.postimg.org/jbo7bw449/test.png'/></div>
            <div class="botLeft">Second line also long and needs to show eclipise</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This working.  I am trying not to specify a width in the right div.

Comment: @BrianMcGinity added another solution of using flexbox, no fixed width. Note, `table-layout:fixed;` is important, to ensure both text boxes to execute ellipsis correctly.

Comment: Wow, that's mind boggling!  I've never heard of flexbox, it works too.  Plus 1 for another solution.  I would accept both answers if I could.